# Factorization of birational maps in char $p$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, resolution-of-singularities, blow-ups

So I was reading about the factorization result that any birational map between smooth varieties is composition of blow-ups and blow-downs with smooth centers. It is apparently true only in characteristics 0 case. I was wondering whether the only reason for that is the resolution of singularities? If we assume resolution of singularities is it true in char $p$? For example if I'm not mistaken resolution of singularities is known to be true for surfaces in char $p$. So does that imply that one can use the factorization theorem for smooth surfaces in char $p$?

Comment: Much more is known about surfaces, independently of the  characteristic: 1) any birational *morphism* is a composition of blow-ups; 2) for any birational map $\varphi $, there is a birational morphism $u$ such that $\varphi \circ u$ is a (birational) morphism. This goes back to Zariski at least, and is much easier than resolution of singularities.

Comment: Thanks I'll search it!

Comment: On the other hand, even in characteristic 0, weak factorisation (in arbitrary dimension) is usually understood to be a bit harder than resolution of singularities (if I understand correctly). Also, the correct statement is not that it is only *true* in characteristic 0, but it is currently only *known* in characteristic 0.